# How to change the selected completion item color for `zsh zstyle list-colors` in .zshrc?

Tags: zsh, zsh-completion

I'm looking to customize the selection color in zsh history and found one example.

```
zstyle ':completion:*' list-colors 'ma=48;2;76;86;106'
```

It works, and I can tinker with the numbers to make changes, but I can't find an explanation for `ma=`.

What is `ma=`?
What is the format for `ma=`?
Is there another approach other than `ma=` to adjust the color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ma=` sets the color for the currently selected completion. See here for more info: https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#Colored-completion-listings

> Is there another approach other than `ma=` to adjust the color?

The link above explains how to adjust them by hand. However, this can be a rather tedious task, which is why I decided to write a Zsh plugin that does it for you: [Z Colors](https://github.com/marlonrichert/zcolors) takes the value of your `$LS_COLORS` and generates from it

- completion colors,
- syntax highlighting colors and
- Git colors.

However, if you do want to go the manual route, have a look at its source code to see how I solved this problem. It’s completely free and open source.